# OrientDB Fulltext Lucene search on embedded property with multiple level document

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, orientdb

I have a property of type "embedded" and I have created a LUCENE index on that property. But it only searches the first level of embedded document

e.g. the property is called "places" and the data stored is in the structure "country.state.city"

`USA:{
     FLORIDA:{
             MIAMI: "Some TEXT"
     }
}`

I need to be able to search on "Some TEXT" which is a city level (3rd level)

Any suggestions on how to run the query to check at city level?

Answer (score -1):

Try this command:

```
select @rid,places[0].City from <Class name>
```

Comment: I actually want to search by city name with LUCENE because it can have multiple cities and the city is at 3rd level, but, we need to be able to search the entire object for country and states too

like example "WHERE places LUCENE "united*" - and it should return the record if either state or countries or cities have the value "united"